# Android APK is somehow verifying package signatures without calling PackageManager.signatures

Tags: android, apk

I'm reverse engineering a **very** popular Android app.

They perform some type of signature verification on the APK, however they do it without:

- Calling `PackageManager.signatures`
- Calling `PackageInfo.signingInfo`
- Instantiating a `JarFile` or `JarEntry`
- Calling native functions(there is a native library with signature verification code, however it has no `JNI_onLoad` and the function is not called)
- Directly accessing the `META-INF` directory
- Utilizing SafetyNet

I have verified that the APK is performing signature verification and not any other type of tamper-detection by resigning the APK and not modifying any files.

The only thing I can think of is that the APK is using reflection to call a method whose signature is encrypted or encoded.

Comment: Have you checked whether they are reading the file manually? Also, did you check for native methods other than JNI_onLoad?

Comment: The native function that has the signature verification code does not get called. And there are no strings that contain "META-INF", so I don't believe that they are reading it manually.

Comment: How SafetyNet is related when verifying the signature of the app?